# determining if a function is small o, big o, or neither of another function

Tags: analysis

Title says it all, really. How is this done in practice?

E.g.; $f(x) = x^2log(x)$ and we want to check if $f(x) = o(x^2)$ or $f(x) = O(x^2)$, as x grows to infinity.

My attempt:

If $f(x) = o(x^2)$, then $f(x)/x^2 \rightarrow$ 0 as x grows large, but this is not true, as $log(x)$ is unbounded.

Also, if $f(x) = O(x^2)$, then it is possible to say $x^2|log(x)| < Cx^2$, but if we divide through by $x^2$, we see that $|log(x)| < C$ which is not possible as the function is unbounded.

Is this how it's done? If not, what are the mistakes, and if yes, are there other ways, especially in regards to the Big O, which the book doesn't really explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

take $f(x) = x^2 $ and take the function $log(x)$ which is monotonically increasing, therefore if you take a large enough constant, take C=100

then $f(x) < Cg(x) \quad \forall x >1$

as $log(x) is monotonically increasing and will be more than one

for example at x = 15

$f(x) = 15^2$ and $g(x) = 15^2 \times log(15) = 15^2 \times 1.17$